# Gravity in a universe where all energy has been turned to mass

Tags: cosmology, gravity, mass, matter

If all energy in the universe was turned to mass would gravity work?

Comment: The same as it always does.  I'd look at classical models of a pure matter, pure energy, and mix of both, in GR.  You can find references in MTW, Robert Wald's text, and just about any other.

Comment: Altho comments aren't the venue for answers, it might help the OP to improve their question if I point out the fact that Penrose's CCC model (which may, given his long & extremely successful career in physics, become the leading one, now that the "measure problem" of field-based inflationary models has remained intractable for decades) has entropy working to clump matter into gravitational fields, whereas a dispersal of mass, during a complete conversion of matter into energy, characterizes the entropic effects of the passage of time, at each end of a past- & future-eternal infinity of aeons.